# What is recommended in VS 2015 where Windows XP is the target platform

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, windows-xp

I am developing a desktop application in Visual Studio 2015 which has to run on Windows XP. I have the following questions:

1. Should I be using Windows Forms or WPF as the preferred development platform?
2. I am developing this on Windows 10 - what is the best way to test this as I do not have access to a Windows XP system?

Comment: Use VMware like virtual machine and work on XP, and winform is recommended, no need for WPF and use VS 2010

Comment: And get .NET FrameWork 4.0 Extended to use (some of the) features from 4.5. Works on XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to the [.NET Framework System Requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you have to use .NET version 4 or below.

Since WPF is running extremely slow under Windows XP, consider to use WinForms.

If your application is fully managed (doesn't contain unmanaged function calls), it is fully compatible with any Windows version. But if desired, you can use virtual machines for testing.

Answer (score 3):

Best way would be testing on a VirtualBox XP and make sure you build your application with Target framework 4.0 as on XP you cannot install 4.5 or later versions of .Net Framework.

And regarding choosing Winform / WPF, it's up to you.